# ¿Por qué no me aparecen los datos que ingresé desde un EXECUTE cuando hago un SELECT?

Tags: sql, sql-server

> Esta es la tabla

```
CREATE DATABASE cita_eps
GO

USE cita_eps
GO

CREATE TABLE tbl_paciente
(   
    identificacionPac INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    apellidoPac NVARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
    nombrePac NVARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
    direccion NVARCHAR (30) NULL,
    celular NVARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    correo NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    estado NVARCHAR (15)NOT NULL,
)
```

> Este es el PROCEDURE

```
USE cita_eps
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE Ingresar_clientes
@pidentificacionPac INTEGER,
@papellidoPac NVARCHAR (25),
@pnombrePac NVARCHAR (25),
@pdireccion NVARCHAR (30),
@pcelular NVARCHAR (10),
@pcorreo NVARCHAR (50),
@pestado NVARCHAR (15)
AS  
    INSERT INTO tbl_paciente (identificacionPac, apellidoPac, nombrePac, direccion, celular, correo, estado)
    VALUES (@pidentificacionPac, @papellidoPac, @pnombrePac, @pdireccion, @pcelular, @pcorreo, @pestado)

EXECUTE Ingresar_clientes 1, 'Newball','Elick', 'Calle 10', '300245658 ', 'elick@gmail.com', 'Activo'
```

> Y este es el SELECT

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_paciente WHERE identificacionPac = 1
```

> Pero cuando ejecuto no aparece nada, he intentado muchas cosas pero no entiendo por qué no me da

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto imagen para dejar más claro a lo que me refiero

Comment: ¿Recibes algún mensaje de error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Añade sentencias GO, a cada uno de los pasos, y verás como te funciona.

```
CREATE DATABASE cita_eps
GO
USE cita_eps
GO
CREATE TABLE tbl_paciente
(   
    identificacionPac INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    apellidoPac NVARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
    nombrePac NVARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
    direccion NVARCHAR (30) NULL,
    celular NVARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    correo NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    estado NVARCHAR (15)NOT NULL,
)
GO
USE cita_eps
GO
CREATE or alter PROCEDURE Ingresar_clientes
@pidentificacionPac INTEGER,
@papellidoPac NVARCHAR (25),
@pnombrePac NVARCHAR (25),
@pdireccion NVARCHAR (30),
@pcelular NVARCHAR (10),
@pcorreo NVARCHAR (50),
@pestado NVARCHAR (15)
AS  
    INSERT INTO tbl_paciente (identificacionPac, apellidoPac, nombrePac, direccion, celular, correo, estado)
    VALUES (@pidentificacionPac, @papellidoPac, @pnombrePac, @pdireccion, @pcelular, @pcorreo, @pestado)
GO  
    EXECUTE Ingresar_clientes 1, 'Newball','Elick', 'Calle 10', '300245658 ', 'elick@gmail.com', 'Activo'
GO  
    select * from dbo.tbl_paciente WHERE identificacionPac = 1
```

[image: Resultado]

Caso contrario, vete verificando paso por paso, lo que tienes.

```
-- Existe la base de datos?
select * from sys.databases s
where s.name ='cita_eps';
-- Existe la tabla?
select * from [cita_eps].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
where t.TABLE_NAME = 'tbl_paciente';
-- Existe el procedure ?
select * from [cita_eps].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES r
where r.ROUTINE_NAME = 'Ingresar_clientes'
-- Existe algún registro en la tabla?
select count(*) from [cita_eps].dbo.tbl_paciente
```